# Accesing a script attached to another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a set of code attached to one of my game objects, that I am trying to access from the script in another object.

I am trying to access the "Move" function in this script:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class MoveBackwards : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     #region Inspector


     public float maxRotationDegrees = 10f;
     public float rotationSpeed = 2f;

     public float maxDistance = 5f;
     public float moveSpeed = 2f;

     #endregion //Inspector

     private float traveledDistance;
     private float rotatedAmount;
     private bool isMoving;

     #region Unity Engine & Events

     private void Update()
     {

         AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

         if(isMoving)
         {
             if(traveledDistance < maxDistance)
             {
                 Vector3 moveDirection = -transform.up;
                 transform.position += moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                 traveledDistance += Mathf.Abs(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
             }
             if(rotatedAmount < maxRotationDegrees)
             {
                 transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                 rotatedAmount += Mathf.Abs(rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
             }
         }
     }

     #endregion //Unity Engine & Events

     public void Move()
     {

         isMoving = true;
     }

 }
```

Using this code:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class PushbackAudio : MonoBehaviour {

     public AudioSource PushbackAudioPilot;
     public AudioSource PushbackApproved;
     public AudioSource PushbackApprovedPRB; //PRB = Pilot read back
     public bool running = true;

     public void AircraftPushbackAudioProcedure()
     {
         StartCoroutine(AircraftPushbackIEnumerator());
     }

    private IEnumerator AircraftPushbackIEnumerator()
     {
         running = true;

         while (running)
         {
             PushbackAudioPilot.Play();
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
             PushbackApproved.Play();
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
             PushbackApprovedPRB.Play();
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
             MoveBackwards = GameObject.Find("Aircraft Sprite").GetComponent<Move>();


         }
     }
 }
```

I am using the line: `MoveBackwards = GameObject.Find("Aircraft Sprite").GetComponent();` but it is giving me two errors:

1. MoveBackwards is a type but is used like a variable
2. The type or namespace name "Move" could not be found (are you
   missing a using a directive or an assembly reference?

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `GameObject.FindObjectOfType()`  or `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("")`

Comment: This does not smell C.

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is clearly not C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using the line: MoveBackwards = GameObject.Find("Aircraft
>   Sprite").GetComponent(); but it is giving me two errors:

That should be:

`MoveBackwards moveBc = GameObject.Find("Aircraft Sprite").GetComponent<MoveBackwards>();`

You can then call the Move function:

```
moveBc.Move();
```

You only missed `<MoveBackwards>` before `()`.